pg_basebackup stuck and does not complete due to EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) on Primary and Secondary(replica) does not finish
I am trying to create a replica using pg_basebackup and every time it gets stuck at a random percentage (80 to 96) percentage. The primary is looping in the getting "recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)"  and the Secondary just loops and gets "Timeout".  What can be issued?  I checked the system resources (like FD, number of processes by Postgres user, etc) everything looks fine.  Is there any clue we can extract from strace?  I don't see any logs or errors in /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-15-main.log.  We are using PSQL psql (PostgreSQL) 15.3 (Ubuntu 15.3-1.pgdg18.04+1).
Primary PSQL:
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 257009
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 8192
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 257009
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

select * from pg_stat_activity where pid=8310
postgres-# ;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+--------------------------------------------------------------
datid            |
datname          |
pid              | 8310
leader_pid       |
usesysid         | 56883
usename          | repmgr
application_name | pg_basebackup
client_addr      | 172.16.82.4
client_hostname  |
client_port      | 44428
backend_start    | 2024-12-10 10:28:34.450436-08
xact_start       |
query_start      | 2024-12-10 10:28:34.538761-08
state_change     | 2024-12-10 10:28:34.538816-08
wait_event_type  | Activity
wait_event       | WalSenderMain
state            | active
backend_xid      |
backend_xmin     |
query_id         |
query            | START_REPLICATION SLOT "repmgr_slot_2" 16/6E000000 TIMELINE 1
backend_type     | walsender

free -hm
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62G         34G         16G        443M         12G         27G
Swap:           15G        1.7G         13G

df -kh
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                      32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    6.3G   12M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/system-root  153G   14G  132G  10% /
tmpfs                     32G  1.2M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                     32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/system-opt   102G  2.1G   95G   3% /opt
/dev/mapper/system-var   230G   87G  132G  40% /var
/dev/sda1                1.5G   69M  1.4G   5% /boot
tmpfs                    6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1003

Strace of PID 8310 ( which involved sending wal and data)
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\235w\0\0\0\26u\177(X\0\0\0\26u\177(\330\0\2\313\355\333z,\216R\0"..., 158, 0, NULL, 0) = 158
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 27607) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "<\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\260(\177u\26\0\0\0\20\t\0\0\373\312\234\25\0 \6\0\177\6\0\0"..., 176, 8333528) = 176
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\315w\0\0\0\26u\177(\330\0\0\0\26u\177)\210\0\2\313\355\333z0\r<\0"..., 206, 0, NULL, 0) = 206
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 27606) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "\256\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`)\177u\26\0\0\0\20\t\0\0\351\7\354a\0 x\0\177\6\0\0"..., 328, 8333704) = 328
sendto(10, "d\0\0\1ew\0\0\0\26u\177)\210\0\0\0\26u\177*\320\0\2\313\355\333z3S\256\0"..., 358, 0, NULL, 0) = 358
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 27605) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "L\0\0\0\355\1|\1\250*\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\213\23/\375\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0"..., 120, 8334032) = 120
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\225w\0\0\0\26u\177*\320\0\0\0\26u\177+H\0\2\313\355\333zD\266L\0"..., 150, 0, NULL, 0) = 150
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 27601) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "R\0\0\0\356\1|\1 +\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\341l\247\20\0 \26\0\177\6\0\0"..., 128, 8334152) = 128
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\235w\0\0\0\26u\177+H\0\0\0\26u\177+\310\0\2\313\355\333zF\333R\0"..., 158, 0, NULL, 0) = 158
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 27600) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "D\0\0\0\357\1|\1\240+\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0z\370S]\0 \10\0\177\6\0\0"..., 112, 8334280) = 112
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\215w\0\0\0\26u\177+\310\0\0\0\26u\177,8\0\2\313\355\333zI\25D\0"..., 142, 0, NULL, 0) = 142
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 27599) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "j\0\0\0\360\1|\1\20,\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\242\v\vd\0 .\0\177\6\0\0"..., 152, 8334392) = 152
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\265w\0\0\0\26u\177,8\0\0\0\26u\177,\320\0\2\313\355\333zKfj\0"..., 182, 0, NULL, 0) = 182
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 27599) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "L\0\0\0\361\1|\1\250,\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\362\f\2738\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0"..., 120, 8334544) = 120
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\225w\0\0\0\26u\177,\320\0\0\0\26u\177-H\0\2\313\355\333zz@L\0"..., 150, 0, NULL, 0) = 150
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 27587) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "L\0\0\0\362\1|\1 -\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0{\360\335\367\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0"..., 120, 8334664) = 120
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\225w\0\0\0\26u\177-H\0\0\0\26u\177-\300\0\2\313\355\333\177T\26L\0"..., 150, 0, NULL, 0) = 150
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 27269) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "J\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\230-\177u\26\0\0\0\20\t\0\0\376\2714\306\0 \24\0\177\6\0\0"..., 200, 8334784) = 200
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\345w\0\0\0\26u\177-\300\0\0\0\26u\177.\210\0\2\313\355\333\177aOJ\0"..., 230, 0, NULL, 0) = 230
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 27266) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "L\0\0\0\364\1|\1`.\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\206\220\341J\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0"..., 120, 8334984) = 120
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\225w\0\0\0\26u\177.\210\0\0\0\26u\177/\0\0\2\313\355\333\211\212\261L\0"..., 150, 0, NULL, 0) = 150
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 26600) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0bd\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "L\0\0\0\365\1|\1\330.\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0]\370&\223\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0"..., 120, 8335104) = 120
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\225w\0\0\0\26u\177/\0\0\0\0\26u\177/x\0\2\313\355\333\211\215uL\0"..., 150, 0, NULL, 0) = 150
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 26599) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "L\0\0\0\366\1|\1P/\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\33\234NP\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0"..., 120, 8335224) = 120
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\225w\0\0\0\26u\177/x\0\0\0\26u\177/\360\0\2\313\355\333\211\227WL\0"..., 150, 0, NULL, 0) = 150
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 26596) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "L\0\0\0\367\1|\1\310/\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\255\217\327\311\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0"..., 120, 8335344) = 120
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\225w\0\0\0\26u\177/\360\0\0\0\26u\1770h\0\2\313\355\333\212\2649L\0"..., 150, 0, NULL, 0) = 150
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 26523) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "L\0\0\0\370\1|\1@0\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\375\345\21\231\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0"..., 120, 8335464) = 120
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\225w\0\0\0\26u\1770h\0\0\0\26u\1770\340\0\2\313\355\333\214y(L\0"..., 150, 0, NULL, 0) = 150
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 26407) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "R\0\0\0\371\1|\1\2700\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0h\266\304\212\0 \26\0\177\6\0\0"..., 200, 8335584) = 200
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\345w\0\0\0\26u\1770\340\0\0\0\26u\1771\250\0\2\313\355\333\214|`R\0"..., 230, 0, NULL, 0) = 230
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 26407) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "D\0\0\0\372\1|\1\2001\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\313\365\352E\0 \10\0\177\6\0\0"..., 112, 8335784) = 112
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\215w\0\0\0\26u\1771\250\0\0\0\26u\1772\30\0\2\313\355\333\214\177\nD\0"..., 142, 0, NULL, 0) = 142
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 26406) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "j\0\0\0\373\1|\1\3601\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\237\210\276\7\0 .\0\177\6\0\0"..., 152, 8335896) = 152
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\265w\0\0\0\26u\1772\30\0\0\0\26u\1772\260\0\2\313\355\333\214\202\300j\0"..., 182, 0, NULL, 0) = 182
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 26405) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0bd\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "Q\0\0\0\374\1|\1\2102\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0XuO\236\0 \25\0\177\6\0\0"..., 128, 8336048) = 128
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\235w\0\0\0\26u\1772\260\0\0\0\26u\17730\0\2\313\355\333\214\376[Q\0"..., 158, 0, NULL, 0) = 158
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2019165936, u64=94023148242672}}], 1, 26373) = 1
read(11, "\27\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0DY\0\0k\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 128
recvfrom(10, 0x7ffe06388c27, 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pread64(7, "L\0\0\0\375\1|\1\0103\177u\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\31\177O\251\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0"..., 120, 8336176) = 120
sendto(10, "d\0\0\0\225w\0\0\0\26u\17730\0\0\0\26u\1773\250\0\2\313\355\333\215^ZL\0"..., 150, 0, NULL, 0) = 150
epoll_wait(6, ^Cstrace: Process 8310 detached

Secondary:
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1db32c, 224484, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=353000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=352574})
recvfrom(6, "\0\0\0\33\351$\0\0\0$\351\22\0\0\0\20\0\36 \310 \v+\262\25\0\0\0\0\0\0\21"..., 224484, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, "\35\16\0\0\0\254\35)\0\0\0\312\35,\0\0\0:\36\30\0\0\0Y\36\22\0\0\0\265\36\n"..., 223336, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, "\304\r\0\0\0d\306\r\0\0\0\34\307\f\0\0\0\n\310(\0\0\0\f\311\30\0\0\0008\312\t"..., 222188, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1dc0a0, 221040, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=352000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=351999})
recvfrom(6, "I#\0\0\0\20M/\0\0\0\23N2\0\0\0\206P\21\0\0\0qS\26\0\0\0\254X2"..., 221040, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2296
recvfrom(6, "\0\0<\323{\1\230\324\206s\26\0\0\0\0\v\0\0\352\274\206M\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0ld"..., 218744, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, "\0\0ld\0\0f\257\1\0I\n\0\0\377\2\0\0i\370.\0\20\0\226#\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 217596, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1dd290, 216448, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=351000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=350999})
recvfrom(6, "\0\0\0nl\271\355\313\2\0\320\266v\271\355\313\2\0\rmajor\301Datapat"..., 216448, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2296
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1ddb88, 214152, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=351000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=350999})
recvfrom(6, "\0\7K\25\0\0\0\374N'\0\0\0 P\23\0\0\0\375P\25\0\0\0fQ\21\0\0\0]"..., 214152, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2296
recvfrom(6, " VJARHORTR01/MPLS-AIRTEL-4G to C"..., 211856, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1de8fc, 210708, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=351000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=350999})
recvfrom(6, "\244\0\301\27\0\0<\323{\1\200\364\206s\26\0\0\0\0\v\0\0o=\221;\0\20\0\0\214\27"..., 210708, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2296
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1df1f4, 208412, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=351000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=350999})
recvfrom(6, "\0\0\0?\226(\0\0\0\236\227\24\0\0\0\366\227\22\0\0\0004\230\25\0\0\0Y\230(\0\0"..., 208412, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2296
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1dfaec, 206116, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=351000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=350999})
recvfrom(6, "\0\0\0\335\277\r\0\0\0\10\3004\0\0\0W\305,\0\0\0006\307\v\0\0\0\37\311\16\0\0"..., 206116, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2296
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1e03e4, 203820, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=350000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=349999})
recvfrom(6, "\0X\220 \0008\220 \0\30\220 \0\370\217 \0\330\217 \0\270\217 \0\230\217 \0\210\217 "..., 203820, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, "\25\0\0\0\0\0\0\244\345\34\0\20\0(+\262\25\0\0\0\0\0\0\345\3440\0\20\0)+\262"..., 202672, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1e0cdc, 201524, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=350000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=349999})
recvfrom(6, "M\"\0\0\0\24N3\0\0\0\210P\4\0\0\0sS\27\0\0\0\255X4\0\0\0\357X\35"..., 201524, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2296
recvfrom(6, "\0*\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0<\323{\1P\16\207s\26\0\0\0\0\v\0\0?\30"..., 199228, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, "\0\10\214 \0\350\213 \0\250\213 \0h\213 \0H\213 \0\30\213 \0\370\212 \0\310\212 "..., 198080, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, "\354\"\0\20\0%+\262\25\0\0\0\0\0\0\366\354\36\0\20\0'+\262\25\0\0\0\0\0\0\261"..., 196932, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1e2348, 195784, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=350000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=349999})
recvfrom(6, "\0\0\0/\334\36\0\0\0\337\334\34\0\0\0\250\335\35\0\0\0\263\335\21\0\0\0\335\336\27\0\0"..., 195784, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1e27c4, 194636, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=349000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=348999})
recvfrom(6, "\0\0\0/\233\10\0\0\0i\233\10\0\0\0|\233\3\0\0\0\204\233/\0\0\0\36\235\t\0\0"..., 194636, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, "\0\0\0\3746\22\0\0\0g7\2\0\0\0%84\0\0\0\0039-\0\0\0\2669!\0\0"..., 193488, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1e30bc, 192340, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=349000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=348999})
recvfrom(6, "\0\0\0\t\f\21\0\0\0\375\f\32\0\0\0\25\r-\0\0\0 \r\20\0\0\0)\r\36\0\0"..., 192340, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2296
recvfrom(6, "\0\330\220@\1\30\217 \0\370\216 \0008\220@\1(\217 \0\10\217 \0\0\0j\370\v\0\20"..., 190044, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1e3e30, 188896, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=349000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=348999})
recvfrom(6, "\354\36\0\0\0\366\354&\0\0\0005\355-\0\0\0|\355\35\0\0\0\241\355\10\0\0\0\364\356\f"..., 188896, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2296
recvfrom(6, "(\23\0\0\0008)\36\0\0\0\200)\7\0\0\0\211)$\0\0\0\305)\r\0\0\0\33*\5"..., 186600, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1e4ba4, 185452, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=349000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=348999})
recvfrom(6, "\262\25\0\0\0\0\200\373\307\271\355\313\2\0h\223\331\271\355\313\2\0\21cleared\277D"..., 185452, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, "\0\0-6\306\375\0\20\0\0d\33t\2\3\177\6\0\0ld\0\0e\257\1\0~\7\0\0\377"..., 184304, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, "\0\0\0\364\363\27\0\20\0\25 \262\25\0\0\0\0\0\0\313\362\36\0\20\0\25 \262\25\0\0\0"..., 183156, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1e5918, 182008, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=348000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=347723})
recvfrom(6, "\25\0\0\0\0\0\0\375\347'\0\20\0\25 \262\25\0\0\0\0\0\0!\347\4\0\20\0\25 \262"..., 182008, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, "\334\1\0\0\0A\335\r\0\0\0\314\336\27\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\32 \260 \37 \262\25\0\0\0"..., 180860, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1148
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1e6210, 179712, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=348000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=347999})
recvfrom(6, "e!\0\0\0Kf\33\0\0\0Kf\35\0\0\0\177f$\0\0\0\201f\22\0\0\0\ng0"..., 179712, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2296
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1e6b08, 177416, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=347000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=346998})
recvfrom(6, "\0\0\0\332C\36\0\0\0\346C\3\0\0\0\347C'\0\0\0CD\25\0\0\0\202E\3\0\0"..., 177416, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1342
recvfrom(6, 0x7fc06b1e7046, 176074, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(7, "\241\0\0\0<\323{\1\310+\206s\26\0\0\0\0\n\0\0e\316|\\\0 p\0\177\6\0\0"..., 86040) = 86040
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=347000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=311466})
recvfrom(6, "d\0\0\0\225w\0\0\0\26s\207|\10\0\0\0\26s\207|\200\0\2\313\355\272%\214rL\0"..., 262144, 0, NULL, NULL) = 150
write(7, "L\0\0\0=\323{\1\340{\207s\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0#\225f\242\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0"..., 120) = 120
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=311000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=309985})
recvfrom(6, "d\0\0\0\345w\0\0\0\26s\207|\200\0\0\0\26s\207}H\0\2\313\355\272%\220kR\0"..., 262144, 0, NULL, NULL) = 230
write(7, "R\0\0\0>\323{\1X|\207s\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\345\350\313:\0 \26\0\177\6\0\0"..., 200) = 200
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0})
recvfrom(6, "d\0\0\0\225w\0\0\0\26s\207}H\0\0\0\26s\207}\300\0\2\313\355\272%\221\356L\0"..., 262144, 0, NULL, NULL) = 150
write(7, "L\0\0\0?\323{\1 }\207s\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0r\341\344\0\0 \20\0\177\6\0\0"..., 120) = 120
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=309000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=308787})
recvfrom(6, "d\0\0\0\215w\0\0\0\26s\207}\300\0\0\0\26s\207~0\0\2\313\355\272%\225\352D\0"..., 262144, 0, NULL, NULL) = 142
write(7, "D\0\0\0@\323{\1\230}\207s\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0\\\272\2\302\0 \10\0\177\6\0\0"..., 112) = 112
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=308000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=307461})
recvfrom(6, "d\0\0\0\335w\0\0\0\26s\207~0\0\0\0\26s\207~\360\0\2\313\355\272%\233\255<\0"..., 262144, 0, NULL, NULL) = 222
write(7, "<\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10~\207s\26\0\0\0\20\t\0\0x\r\305\10\0 \6\0\177\6\0\0"..., 192) = 192
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=307000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=305420})
recvfrom(6, "d\0\0\0\265w\0\0\0\26s\207~\360\0\0\0\26s\207\177\210\0\2\313\355\272%\243bj\0"..., 262144, 0, NULL, NULL) = 182
write(7, "j\0\0\0B\323{\1\310~\207s\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0;\240W\232\0 .\0\177\6\0\0"..., 152) = 152
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=305000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=304065})
recvfrom(6, "d\0\0\0\215w\0\0\0\26s\207\177\210\0\0\0\26s\207\177\370\0\2\313\355\272%\250\0D\0"..., 262144, 0, NULL, NULL) = 142
write(7, "D\0\0\0C\323{\1`\177\207s\26\0\0\0@\n\0\0V\222\316\241\0 \10\0\177\6\0\0"..., 112) = 112
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=304000}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=303683})
recvfrom(6, "d\0\0\0\315w\0\0\0\26s\207\177\370\0\0\0\26s\207\200\250\0\2\313\355\272%\253\253j\0"..., 262144, 0, NULL, NULL) = 206
write(7, "j\0\0\0D\323{\1\20\321\5\0\1\0\0\0\0\200\207s\26\0\0\0b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 176) = 176
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(7, [4 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=8, tv_usec=303000}^Cstrace: Process 16871 detached
 <detached ...>

